# Prevent "Define" from showing in the edit menu

Tags: ios

In order to prevent "Define" as well as other menu items from showing when tapping on a textfield, i basically return NO for the canPerformAction:withSender method for each action.
This works perfectly accept for one problem in preventing the "Define" menu item from showing up. I have to use _define: which is not allowed in the rules because it has an underscore and therefore is deemed a private api reference and therefore the IOS app will get rejected.
It works but i cannot use it. The other menu items such as Copy, Select, etc. don't require underscore.
What to do? 
Below is a code snippet containing "define" which works perfectly but i cannot use it.

...

```
 else if (action == @selector(paste:)) {
     retValue = NO;
 }
 else if (action == @selector(_define:)) {
     retValue = NO;
 }
 else {
     retValue = [super canPerformAction:action withSender:sender];
 }
```

...

Comment: Hmmm...any chance of only returning YES for selected ones you allow?

Comment: Actually i don't want anything edit menu items to show up.

Comment: Then I guess I don't understand why a simple `return NO;` isn't useful.

Comment: Well, I could just simply return NO from the method but will that work without causing some other problems? I mean, could I accidentally prevent some other action that is not part of the edit menu to be obstructed if i just return NO.

Comment: It looks like `canPerformAction:withSender:` is only used for menu actions, so there shouldn't be any undesirable side effects to returning `NO` unconditionally. (Well, they could start using it for non-menu actions which you might want to allow in a future iOS release, but I'd say you needing to change your code to account for that is their design bug, not yours.)

Comment: Thanks to everyone's comments. I will simply return NO in this case.

Comment: JFYI:My app is rejected because of _define:. Resolution center says the reason is "2.5: Apps that use non-public APIs will be rejected".