# How to remove or disable "Define" option when selecting text in an HTML input control on an iOS 7 WebView?

Tags: javascript, html, ios, ios7, webview

I have a simple input (type="text") html control being displayed inside a WebView in our iOS application.

When the text is selected inside the input control, an iOS dialog automatically appears with four options: "Cut", "Copy", "Replace...", and "Define". I need to be able to remove or disable, at minimum, the "Define" option.

The reason for this is because our application is typically used for connecting to another device on a local area network lacking an internet connection.  When the "Define" option is pressed, it would appear iOS attempts to make some sort of internet request to search for something. When there is no internet connection present, the iOS application appears to lock up for a full 5-10 seconds, wrecking all sorts of havoc in our application.

Is there any sort of CSS, HTML META, or iOS option to prevent the "Define" option from being available?

In case anyone is confused, here is an example of what I'm talking about:

[image: example]

Answer (score 0):

By using css you can prevent selection of the text, so menu will not apper( with user-select:none).

Also you can disable this menu to show using this link [prevent define from showing in edit menu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10195311/prevent-define-from-showing-in-the-edit-menu)

Comment: Preventing CSS selection is not an option.

I will investigate your link though, thanks.

Comment: The link you provided does not appear to work for me for some reason.  

-(BOOL)canPerformAction:(SEL)action withSender:(id)sender{return NO;} does nothing.

I've attempted to both subclass my UIWebView and add the method onto my owning UIViewController, neither appear to work.  Am I not understanding it correctly?